# Can you put 2 circles inside of one Button

Tags: html, css, button

I want to make a 1€ coin with CSS but I have the problem that I can't give it it's characteristic shape consisting of two circles. I don't want to use multiple divs for making the two circles because I want to have it as a Button. Is there any way to put 2 different shapes in one button tag or are you forced to use divs?

Here is my failed attempt at trying to do so:

```css
.btnCircle1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.btnCircle2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btnCircle1 btnCircle2"></button>
```

Comment: so you want a div, with first circle grey, then a second circle yellow? if so, I will answer

Comment: You could investigate before/after pseudo elements and/or radial-gradient backgrounds.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Yes I want a button with two circles. I think a div would work the same but honestly I don't know.

Comment: use border + outline + box-shadow (you can have a lot of box-shadow)

Comment: it seems you are over complicating a simple task. All you need is to use the default border feature

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```css
.btnCircle {
  /* here just change one value, to change the other automatically */
  /* for example you can use a responsive unit (that change often) like `vw` and the other element will automatically changed automatically */
  --bigCirle-Height: 100px; 
  height: var(--bigCirle-Height);
  width: var(--bigCirle-Height);
  /* is always a perfect circle */
  border-radius: var(--bigCirle-Height);
  border: none; /* Remove default borders */
  /* add this to make the ::before works */
  position: relative;
}

.btnCircle::before {
  /* change this value 1 means bigger, the smaller is the number (for example 0.7) the yellow circle is smaller */
  /* using css variables and calculations the money it will be always responsive to the parent height */
  --smallCirle-Height: calc(var(--bigCirle-Height) * 0.7);
  content: '1€';
  height: var(--smallCirle-Height);
  width: var(--smallCirle-Height);
  border-radius: var(--smallCirle-Height);
  background: yellow;
  /* this two lines will center the circle */
  /* inset is like writing top: 50%, left: 50% */
  inset: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* center the text inside circle */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  /* positioning absolutely */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btnCircle"></button>
```

Comment: why not using the border feature? background + border and no need pseudo element and complex code

Comment: yes, this is a good solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif Never thought of that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

as A Haworth mentioned you, one way is using the before/after pseudo elements
here's an example:

```css
.btnCircle {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  padding: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.btnCircle::after {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 10px;
  content: '';
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="btnCircle"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

- One you can use `background` and `border`.

```css
/*With background and border css start*/

.btnCircle1 {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 15px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


/*With background and border css end*/


/*With pesudo element css start*/

.btnCircle1-psd {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.btnCircle1-psd::before,
.btnCircle1-psd::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btnCircle1-psd::after {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  background-color: blue;
}


/*With pesudo element css end*/


/*With radial gradient background color start*/

.btnCircle1-bg {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 160, 255, 1) 50%);
}


/*With radial gradient background color end*/


/*With box inset shadow color start*/

.btnCircle1-shadow {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  border: none;
  z-index: 99;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
}


/*With box inset shadow color end*/
```

```html
<h1> With background and border</h1>
<button type="button" class="btnCircle1">1$</button>
<h1> With radial gradient background color</h1>
<button type="button" class="btnCircle1-bg">1$</button>
<h1> With box inset shadow color</h1>
<button type="button" class="btnCircle1-shadow">1$</button>
<h1>With pesudo element <strong>before</strong> and <strong>after</strong>.</h1>
<button type="button" class="btnCircle1-psd">1$</button>
```